# Qt 5.6 install issue

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, vtk, point-cloud-library, qt5.6

I am really new to programming and Linux and I want to install PCL. 
Now I want to install VTK and Qt 5.6. So I followed the steps on this site:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Linux

When I want to configure VTK I get this error:

CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5UiPlugin" with
  any of the following names:

```
Qt5UiPluginConfig.cmake
qt5uiplugin-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5UiPlugin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5UiPlugin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5UiPlugin" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:142 (find_package)

I searched the internet and got this:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65284-vtk-integration-with-Qt-5-5

How can I recompile a programm? Can somebody help? I am really frustrated...
Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

What distro are you using? If you're on ubuntu you should try this:

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope that helps.